# How to prevent image slider from scrolling too much?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a slider and one of its function is being able to be move to next and previous by mouse event.

It is already working but the problem is that when it reaches the end, it keeps scrolling. Here is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/385YR/).

Any idea?

```
var sliding,
    dir, 
    startClientX = 0,
    prevClientX = 0,
    $mainDiv = $('#main-div');

function move(dir, step) {
   var $ul = $mainDiv.find('.slider'),
       liWidth = $ul.find('div').width();

   $ul.animate({
      left: '+=' + (dir * liWidth)
   }, 200);
}

$mainDiv.mousedown(function (event) {
    sliding = true;
    startClientX = event.clientX;
    return false;
}).mouseup(function (event) {
    var step = event.clientX - startClientX, 
        dir = step > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    step = Math.abs(step);

    move(dir, step);
});
```

Comment: You mean too much or too fast? Because you gave `left: '+=' + (dir * liWidth)`.

Comment: I mean,. for example, I have only 3 DIV, when reaching the 3rd one, it still scroll which displays a blank. vice versa

Comment: Yes it is scrolling too much. Even no more image to display

Comment: You can see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623549/how-to-prevent-image-slider-from-scrolling-too-much/23624222#23624222)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing custom javascript code, I would suggest going for using jQuery cycle2 plugin that will make your life easier.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Comment: I think, this would be posted as a comment not an answer

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Yeah you are right! But I thought it will be helpful for others too if I post it as an answer coz comments go unnoticed many a times.

Comment: OP focus is important here. Sometimes, they ask javascript ajax questions, but we answer in javascript not offer jquery. Because this is common things. Maybe, OP wants to develop a slider to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/385YR/1/)**

You need to check if slider reached left or not;

```
var sliding,
    dir, 
    startClientX = 0,
    prevClientX = 0,
    $mainDiv = $('#main-div');

function move(dir, step) {
   var $ul = $mainDiv.find('.slider'),
       liWidth = $ul.find('div').width();
   var childCount = $(".slider div").length;
    if (((childCount - 1) * liWidth + getLeftPos()) <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
   $ul.animate({
      left: '+=' + (dir * liWidth)
   }, 200);
}

function getLeftPos() {
    var childPos = $(".slider").offset();
    var parentPos = $(".slider").parent().offset();
    return (childPos.left - parentPos.left);
}
$mainDiv.mousedown(function (event) {
    sliding = true;
    startClientX = event.clientX;
    return false;
}).mouseup(function (event) {
    var step = event.clientX - startClientX, 
        dir = step > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    step = Math.abs(step);

    move(dir, step);
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. when it reach the end, it doesn't go to the previous anymore.

Comment: when it reachs end, it must go first one?

Comment: when it reach the end, it must be enabled to go to previous.